# Laravel API - protecting route access

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-5, routes

I am building a RESTful Laravel 5.1 API. I only want to allow my frontend Angular app to access certain routes, but currently all the routes are simply exposed.

I was going to use `auth middleware` to check that my frontend app is authorized to access a route:

```
    $router->get('/sensitiveData', ['middleware' => 'auth',
        'Resources\Questions@getSensitiveData'
    ]);
```

But this is good for checking a specific user.

How can I protect my routes such that only specified client apps can access routes? Should I be registering a ClientID somewhere? How can I specify this?

Comment: I think the best way would be to use token-based authentication or oauth implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Check this package

[**api-guard**](https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard)

Usage

In your controller extend the `ApiGuardController`
this way your api is private , you can access it only when using an Authorization token

You can find more informations and Options in the docs (like how to create the private api-key or Turning off authentication for a specific method ..etc)

there is no need to set a middleware for it.